# Yup conditional validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I want to validate an event with yup validatesync

Input is an object containing an object with 3 fields. field 1 is required. either field 2 or 3 should be present in the input. or use the default value.

Below is the code used, The default value is not being used when the field is empty in input.

***eg: if filed 2 is present so filed3 is optional to be present in the input but it should use the default value from the scheme.***

```
obj = { "node": { "node1": { "filed1": "value1", "filed2": "value2", "filed3": "value3" } } }

validate = () => yup.object({
    node1: yup.object({
      node2: yup.object().shape({
        filed1: yup.string().required(),
        filed2: yup.string().when('filed3', {
          is: (filed3: string) => filed3.length === 0,
          then: yup.string().required(),
          otherwise: yup.string().default('my defaut1'),
        }),
        filed3: yup.string().when('filed2', {
          is: (filed2: string) => !filed2 || filed2.length === 0,
          then: yup.string().required(message),
          otherwise: yup.string().default('my defaut2'),
        }),
      },
      [ [ 'filed2', 'filed3' ] ]
      ).required(),
    }),   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems almost to be working already.
I have tried several things and it seems like this behavior has some issues. Anyway, still I've found a solution to your problem :
First don't use `.length`, if the string is undefined that will throw. Prefer a `!filedNUMBER`everywhere.
Than add `default(...)` also on the required key. You will end up with something like this :

```
obj = { "node": { "node1": { "filed1": "value1", "filed2": "value2", "filed3": "value3" } } }

validate = () => yup.object({
    node1: yup.object({
      node2: yup.object().shape({
        filed1: yup.string().required(),
        filed2: yup.string().when('filed3', {
          is: (filed3: string) => !filed3,
          then: yup.string().required().default('my defaut1'),
          otherwise: yup.string().default('my defaut1'),
        }),
        filed3: yup.string().when('filed2', {
          is: (filed2: string) => !filed2,
          then: yup.string().required(message).default('my defaut2'),
          otherwise: yup.string().default('my defaut2'),
        }),
      },
      [ [ 'filed2', 'filed3' ] ]
      ).required(),
    }),   })
```

Comment: Adding default value in ''then'' leads to field ''not required'' state. even if field 2 and 3 is not present, it will take the default values and proceed. My requirement is to make either one of the filed to be required.